# Span frame over two columns tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have tried making a simple tkinter application which has 3 frames, one on top (column 0, row 0), one on the left (column 0, row 1), and one on the bottom right (column 1, row 1). Is there a way to span the top frame (toolframe) through two columns? Code is below:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.title("Application")
root.geometry("1000x1000")

s=ttk.Style()
s.configure('TFrame', background='gray')
s.configure('windowframes.TFrame', background='darkgray')

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="2 2 2 2",height=300)
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N,E,S,W))

toolframe = ttk.Frame(mainframe,height=60,style='windowframes.TFrame')
toolframe.grid(column=0, row=0, rowspan=1,sticky=(N,E,W), padx=2, pady=2)
mainframe.columnconfigure(0,weight=2)

hierarchyframe = ttk.Frame(mainframe,width=260,style='windowframes.TFrame')
hierarchyframe.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=(S,W,N), padx=2, pady=2)
mainframe.rowconfigure(1,weight=1)

graphicframe = ttk.Frame(mainframe,style='windowframes.TFrame')
graphicframe.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=(N,S,E,W), padx=2, pady=2)
mainframe.rowconfigure(1,weight=1)
mainframe.columnconfigure(1,weight=1)

root.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: use `columnspan` argument and set it to 2: `columnspan=2` in the grid method

Comment: Have you read through all of the grid documentation? It documents how to have widgets span columns.